# Doxygen not seeing(linking?) comments

Tags: doxygen

As you can see below, I am having some problems with Doxygen not linking my comments correctly. It seems to do this sparatically, as I have all my comments with the same structure, but these ones consistantly throw this error.

You may be able to tell that I have my functions declared in my '.h' files, and defined in my '.cpp' files.

Any idea on how I can solve this? I have 100+ functions, and these three seem to be causing issues, none of the other ones. Not sure why, or how to resolve this. Any ideas?

```
DebugDataLoggingClass.cpp:46: warning: documented function `void RetrievalRig::DebugDataLoggingClass::AddEntryToCSV' was not declared or defined.

DebugDataLoggingClass.cpp:55: warning: documented function `void RetrievalRig::DebugDataLoggingClass::AddEntryToCSV' was not declared or defined.

RetrievalRigClass.cpp:416: warning: documented function `void RetrievalRig::RetrievalRigClass::DebugClosedHandler' was not declared or defined.

DebugDataLoggingClass.h:22: warning: Member DebugDataLoggingClass::AddEntryToCSV(System::String^ Name, double Value) (function) of class RetrievalRig::DebugDataLoggingClass is not documented.

DebugDataLoggingClass.h:23: warning: Member DebugDataLoggingClass::AddEntryToCSV(System::DateTime Date) (function) of class RetrievalRig::DebugDataLoggingClass is not documented.

RetrievalRigClass.h:188: warning: Member RetrievalRigClass::DebugClosedHandler(Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosedEventArgs^ e) (function) of class RetrievalRig::RetrievalRigClass is not documented.
```

EDIT: After not touching the code for 10 days, I came back to work today and found that only four of the original 6 errors still exist. The functions it is complaining about have the same name, but different arguments being passed to them. Does Doxygen not support this, or do I need to use some sort of explicit syntax? Off to scour the internet for answers...

EDIT2: Added code

```
/**
 * The values in the CSV file must be formatted appropriately. This method
 * accomplishes this for a set of a string and double. this is used for all
 * values in the datarecord.
 * @param Name  The name of the value to be written to the file
 * @param Value The current value to be written to the file
 */
void DebugDataLoggingClass::AddEntryToCSV(System::String^ Name, double Value){
    this->DataFileWriter->WriteLine(Name+","+Value);
}

/**
 * The values in the CSV file must be formatted properly, this method 
 * accomplishes this for a set consisting of a string and date. this is used
 * for the timestamp of each datarecord.
 * @param Date [description]
 */
void DebugDataLoggingClass::AddEntryToCSV(System::DateTime Date){
    this->DataFileWriter->WriteLine("Time ,"+Date);
}
```

Comment: You will get the "was not declared or defined" warning if doxygen finds a member definition without having encountered a declaration. This could be due to missing input, conditional sections (#if..) or a parsing problem in doxygen. If you have a self-contained example showing this problem, please file a bug report in doxygen's bug tracker (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen)

Comment: Sorry, went on vacation for the past many days, just getting back to this... I cannot figure this out, since it complains about not knowing where the function is written, while also complaining that it cannot find the prototype (atleast that's how I read these errors)... It seems to be a parsing issue, although since you mention it, I may need to investigate the #ifdef's I have. I'll see what I can figure out and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Updated OP, please read.

Comment: Could you please share the actual doxygen comment that you have for these methods? There could be some tricky syntax mistake.

Comment: done. The code above is in the .cpp file and the declaration is in the .h file with no comment.